# Как правильно реализовать валидацию загрузки файлов?

Tags: php

Вот код, который руководит загрузкой

```
<?php
session_start();
$data = array();

if( isset( $_GET['uploadfiles'] ) ){  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = './папка для загрузки/';
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    foreach( $_FILES as $file ){
        //как здесь сделать валидацию, которая бы пропускала указанные расширения?
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . basename($file['name']) ) ){
            $files[] = realpath( $uploaddir . $file['name'] );
            $fil[] = $file['name'];
        }
        else{
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    $data = $error ? array('error' => 'Ошибка') : array('files' => $fil );
    $_SESSION['files'] = $fil;
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

Я так понимаю, нужно добавить `if` в `foreach`, который будет проверять расширение?
Нашел такой вариант, но здесь можно указать MIME-тип

```
if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "image/gif") {
   echo "Sorry, we only allow uploading GIF images";
   exit;
 }
```

Нужно разбить регуляркой имя файла на его название и расширение, и другой регуляркой проверить расширение?

Comment: Что-то сипьно много неточностей... Проверяете `$_GET['uploadfiles']` но используете`$_FILES`. А это ведь разные переменные. Да и регулярки для простых задач использовать - не оптимально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доверять расширениям и mime type нельзя! их можно подделать. У GD/Imagemagic есть функции которые проверяют тип файла по-настоящему.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyimage.php

Так же, создание и проверка наличия дерикторий в коде, плохая идея. Дериктории нужно создавать deploy/build скриптом заранее.

Пример кода с `exif-imagetype`

```
<?php

  $uploaddir     = 'abc/def/';
  $fileSizeLimit = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5Mb
  $allowedTypes  = [
    IMAGETYPE_GIF,
    IMAGETYPE_JPEG,
    IMAGETYPE_PNG,
    IMAGETYPE_BMP,
    IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II,
    IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM
  ];

  foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      // upload error
      continue;
    }

    $destName = $uploaddir . $file['name'];
    if (!moveFile($file['tmp_name'], $destName)) {
      // Can not move file
      continue;
    }

    if (!validateFile($destName, $fileSizeLimit, $allowedTypes)) {
      // Your file is wrong
      removeFile($destName);
      continue;
    }

    // All good. Do your stuff
  }

  // Helper functions
  function moveFile($from, $to)
  {
    return move_uploaded_file($from, $to);
  }

  function removeFile($name)
  {
    unlink($name);
  }

  function validateFile($name, $size, $typeList)
  {
    if (!validateFileSize($name, $size)) {
      return false;
    }

    return validateFileType($name, $typeList);
  }

  function validateFileSize($name, $maxSizeLimit)
  {
      return filesize($name) <= $maxSizeLimit;
  }

  function validateFileType($name, $types)
  {
    return in_array(
      exif_imagetype($name),
      $types,
      true // Strict
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ниже простейший код для валидации изображений по расширению и размеру. Можно еще дополнительно поставить проверку по `mime_content_type`.

```
<?php 

$imgFile = $_FILES['imgURL']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['imgURL']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['imgURL']['size'];


                        if(empty($imgFile)){
                            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
                        }
                        else // if not empty
                        {


    $upload_dir = '../user_images/'; // upload directory

    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

    // valid image extensions
    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

    // rename uploading image
//  $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
    $userpic = $imgFile;

    // allow valid image file formats
    if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){

    // check if there is already file with the same name
    if (file_exists ($upload_dir.$userpic)) {
    $errMSG = "File with such name already exists";
    }

        // Check file size '5MB'
        if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
        }
        else{
            $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        }
    }
    else{
        $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    }

} // cycle end


?>
```

Comment: Не "можно ещё дополнительно поставить проверку на mime", а нужно!

Comment: Спасибо, но я хотел просто дополнить код в вопросе валидацией